# Google Places Autocomplete API filter by multiple countries

Tags: javascript, google-places-api

Looking for a way to filter the autocomplete results filtered by 2 countries, Canada and US.

Currently I can only filter by one or the other with options like this...

```
var options = {
  types: ['(cities)'],
  componentRestrictions: {country: 'us'}
}
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input,options);
```

... but I have not seen any documentation that explains how to restrict autocomplete results to 2 countries.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Google Places API does not currently support this feature. If you believe this would be a useful feature you can submit a 'Places API - Feature Request' [here](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Places%20API%20-%20Feature%20Request).

**UPDATE**

This feature was introduced in version 3.27 of Maps JavaScript API in January 2017:

> You can now restrict Autocomplete predictions to only surface from multiple countries. You can do this by specifying up to 5 countries in the componentRestrictions field of the AutocompleteOptions.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/releases
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#ComponentRestrictions

Comment: Two years later it wasn't added yet :(

Comment: Instead, just star this issue: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4233 - It was created back in 2012 thought. Good luck